# iframe embed moving towards the left on screen resize

Tags: html, css, fonts

So I have made a projects page in which the iframe embed keeps going to the left when screen resize but I want it to be in the `centre` instead of being on the left side:

[image]

```css
.hr {
  height: 5px;
  width: calc((160vw)/2);
  background-color: #181818;
  position: relative;
  border-width: 0;
}

.video {
  width: calc((160vw)/2);
  height: calc((90vw)/2); 
  border : 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>
    <body class='container'>

    <hr class='hr'>
    <br class='us'>

    <iframe frameBorder="0" class='video' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/inBBuwcLwH8'></iframe>

    <br class='us'>
    <hr class='hr'>

    </body>
```

I've tried adding `margin` to the left but it seems to move to the right when the screen isn't resized

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `display: block; margin: 0 auto;` to `iframe` tag

```css
.hr {
  height: 5px;
  width: calc((160vw)/2);
  background-color: #181818;
  position: relative;
  border-width: 0;
}

.video {
  width: calc((160vw)/2);
  height: calc((90vw)/2); 
  border : 2px solid;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>
    <body class='container'>

    <hr class='hr'>
    <br class='us'>

    <iframe frameBorder="0" class='video' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/inBBuwcLwH8'></iframe>

    <br class='us'>
    <hr class='hr'>

    </body>
```